# Trouble Installing R Package from GitHub

Tags: r, github, installation, package

I'm having trouble installing the following [R package](https://github.com/lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer) from GitHub. I've installed devtools and tried running:

`install_github("lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer")`

But all I get is the following error;

```
Downloading GitHub repo lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\marce\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpesyKBP\remotes6bf041cb1def\lujunyan1118-DrugScreenExplorer-7c98599/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'DrugScreenExplorer': (663ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
    NB: this package now depends on R (>= 3.5.0)
    WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects:  'DrugScreenExplorer/shiny/shinyData.RData'  WARNING: Added dependency on R >= 3.5.0 because serialized objects in  serialize/load version 3 cannot be read in older versions of R.  File(s) containing such objects:  'DrugScreenExplorer/vignettes/src/shiny/shinyData.RData'
-  building 'DrugScreenExplorer_0.1.0.tar.gz'
  
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/marce/OneDrive/Back-Up/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'DrugScreenExplorer' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Fehler in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
 there is no package called 'Rtsne'
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Ausführung angehalten
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'DrugScreenExplorer'
* removing 'C:/Users/marce/OneDrive/Back-Up/Dokumente/R/win-library/4.0/DrugScreenExplorer'
>  Fehler: Failed to install 'DrugScreenExplorer' from GitHub:  
> (konvertiert von Warnung) installation of package
> ‘C:/Users/marce/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpesyKBP/file6bf050512a61/DrugScreenExplorer_0.1.0.tar.gz’
> had non-zero exit status
```

Rtools (which seems to be required to install packages from GitHub) is installed and installing an arbitrary other package works (  `install_github("dill/beyonce")` )
Also trying to install the zip directly through RStudio failed.

Maybe I'm overseeing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: From the error message it seems this package depends on the `Rtsne` package which doesn't appear to be installed. Try installing it first with `install.packages("Rtsne")`

Comment: If you don't find the answer here, this might be a good question to ask at [Bioinformatics StackExchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I got it to install with `remotes::install_github("lujunyan1118/DrugScreenExplorer")`. I needed a couple of dependencies installed from CRAN first though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! (I also contacted the creator, which is a collaborateur). The issue was that the installation required other packages (amongst others "Rtsne"), which had to be installed manually.

Many thanks!